# Unable to register multiple options and post api on lambda api gateway from template.yml file

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

Hi i created post api using nodejs express js for my web application and using aws serverless development process but i am getting issue that when i adding more then one post, Options and Get api than last registered api removed from lambda api gateway and therefore i unable to access that previous api, i tried a lot with different solution but no luck yet.

Here my template.yml code and i attached my lambda api gateway screenshot

AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform:
- AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
- AWS::CodeStar

Parameters:
  ProjectId:
    Type: String
    Description: AWS CodeStar projectID used to associate new resources to team members

```
# Enable blue/green deployments using this Globals section. For instructions, see the AWS CodeStar User Guide:
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codestar/latest/userguide/how-to-modify-serverless-project.html?icmpid=docs_acs_rm_tr
#
# Globals:
#   Function:
#     AutoPublishAlias: live
#     DeploymentPreference:
#       Enabled: true
#       Type: Canary10Percent5Minutes

Resources:
  HelloWorld:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      Environment:
        Variables:
          NODE_ENV: production
      Role:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Join ['-', [!Ref 'ProjectId', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'LambdaTrustRole']]
      Events:
        GetEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: get
        PostEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: post
        OptionsEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /savefundrisk
            Method: options
        PostEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /savefundrisk
            Method: post
        OptionsEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /saveUpdateLog
            Method: options
        PostEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /saveUpdateLog
            Method: post
```

[lambda api gateway screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0SIc.png)